# BigQuery: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/gax/retrying/ExceptionRetryAlgorithm

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm working on a Google Dataflow Java project. I'm trying to create and update BigQuery tables in the initialisation of the pipeline. So, for getting started, I'm trying to instantiate BigQuery Java Client this way:

```
 BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

When running, it brings me the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/gax/retrying/ExceptionRetryAlgorithm
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at com.google.cloud.BaseService.<clinit>(BaseService.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions$DefaultBigQueryFactory.create(BigQueryOptions.java:46)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions$DefaultBigQueryFactory.create(BigQueryOptions.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:426)
    at com.mydomain.Analysis.main(Analysis.java:359)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.gax.retrying.ExceptionRetryAlgorithm
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 17 more
```

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <beam.version>2.19.0</beam.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.110.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Beam -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

From the error it looks like some `.jar` containing  the `com.google.api.gax.retrying.ExceptionRetryAlgorithm.class` is missing.

A quick Google search directed me to add the below dependency to the `pom.xml`. This `gax.jar` contains the `ExceptionRetryAlgorithm` class.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>gax</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I hope that adding the above dependency to your pom resolves the issue.

Comment: https://mavenlibs.com/maven/dependency/com.google.api/gax for the latest. It's on 2.9.10 these days.